# Set ip adress for network interface in Windows XP from java

Tags: java, windows, networking

I need to set IP adress on Windows XP machine from our Java APP. As I do not know any way how to set it purely from java I would like to use  [netsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netsh)   to set it. Howerver as there are more than one interfaces I need to obtain special "long name" of network connection. 
Nethsh command will look like this:

```
 netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

I tried to use

```
NetworkInterface
```

class to obtain it, but without success. For network name on Windows xp it return names like "eth0" :)

I am currently parsing output of command "ipconfig", but not only it is problematic, it also do not scale with various XP language mutations.

Comment: What's the actual higher-level requirement you're trying to solve? There might be a better way to do this; OTOH I wouldn't be too impressed if a Joe Random Application would try to fiddle with the network settings on my machine.

Comment: Timo Geusch: Well. Win Xp are hosting  our application. We remove Win XP interface (explorer). In case of replacing broken box we need to set original IP adress.  DHCP is not available:(

Answer (score 1):

Modify windows registry with Java. These links should help you.

http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/dhcp-static-ip-settings-in-windows-registry

[read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: But surely, the modifications will only take affect at the next reboot.  I think the OP wants the change to take place sooner.

Comment: Wery interesting, I thought about changing registry, but I thought that it will be much more complicated. JRegistry looks very nice.

Comment: While this is also feasable way how to do that I hoped there is some better way, so I did not mark is at accepted answere.

Comment: Stephan, I did not know that you need to reboot to affect changes. I never tried this approach on my own. Thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IPHelper API, you can find on MSDN a lot of examples and documentation. Of course you will have to make native method invocation. This is the link to IP Helper homepage on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Also I could give you a few .net links regarding managed wrappers over native C++ code, but you work on Java.

Comment: I see this option very simillar to previous two (registry, or external app). I hoped for native support, But it look like this is not task for java. By the way extranl app (ipconfing & netsh) works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

**netsh -c interface ip show config**

you see long name of the interface

and next

**netsh interface ip set address "Połączenie lokalne" static 192.168.1.34 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.247 1**

There is help page from M$
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257748/en-us

Comment: This is not answerer to my question. I know that  this is working. but I would like to obtain long name from Java, differently than calling external netsh command and parse it`s output.