# How to set ip address in java

Tags: java, ip

I want to disable the network for testing like this solution in c#: [How to simulate network failure for test purposes (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474803/how-to-simulate-network-failure-for-test-purposes-in-c)  It suggests setting the ip to a bogus static address.  How can I set the ip from Java or Groovy?

[This solution is for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279125/set-ip-adress-for-network-interface-in-windows-xp-from-java).  I'm using Mac.

Comment: Have a look at this [ifconfig](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html) e.g. `sudo ifconfig en1 down` ... `sudo ifconfig en1 up`

Comment: Can I access ifconfig from java?  I am hoping to have a unit test handle the reconfiguration.

Comment: @alexvetter ifconfig is for Linux only

Comment: `ifconfig` should be available on `Mac OS X` and you can run it from a Unit test.  It will cause the network for your whole machine to stop working, not just your test, of course

Comment: I have found how to do this with exec but I don't know what to do about the password requirement of sudo

Comment: @BhavikAmbani No it's not! Did you click on the link? It will show you the Apple man page for ifconfig...

Comment: @AllisonEer You need to change the `/etc/sudoers` file. Search for `sudoers` and `NOPASSWD`.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a proxy for the JVM that drops all the requests ?

You wouldn't have to change your system configuration, proxy handling could be done via fixtures if you want some advanced properties.

That seems to me a way to explore